# Spring Security with LDAP and custom UserDetailsContextMapper

Tags: ldap, spring-security

I am trying to make Spring Security 3.05 to work with a modified UserDetailsContextMapper so that i can get a few more info out of LDAP they way i need to, a task that seems fairly straightforward, but had no success.

I have configured Spring Security to use LDAP authentication with the following beans:

```xml
<bean id="contextSource"
    class="org.springframework.security.ldap.DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource">
    <constructor-arg value="ldaps://192.168.1.102:636" />
    <property name="userDn" value="manager" />
    <property name="password" value="password" />
</bean>

<bean id="ldapAuthProvider"
    class="org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.LdapAuthenticationProvider">
    <constructor-arg>
        <bean class="org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.BindAuthenticator">
            <constructor-arg ref="contextSource" />
            <property name="userSearch">
                <bean id="userSearch" class="org.springframework.security.ldap.search.FilterBasedLdapUserSearch">
                    <constructor-arg index="0" value="" />
                    <constructor-arg index="1" value="(mail={0})" />
                    <constructor-arg index="2" ref="contextSource" />
                </bean> 
            </property>
        </bean>
    </constructor-arg>
    <property name="userDetailsContextMapper" ref="myContextMapper" />
</bean>
```

However even though i have defined `myContextMapper` as:

```xml
<bean id="myContextMapper" class="com.mypackage.MyLDAPUserDetailsMapper">
    <property name="rolePrefix" value="TEST_PREFIX" />
</bean>
```

it does not work. meaning that the custom mapper is ignored (i get no debug output whatsoever).

p.s. applicationContext-security.xml can be seen below and apart from the custom UserDetailsMapper that's been ignored, authentication and role assignment is working fine.

```xml
<authentication-manager>
    <ldap-authentication-provider server-ref="contextSource"/>
</authentication-manager>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't need to configure the in-built UserDetailsContextMapper classes. Spring Security automatically picks up the correct `UserDetailsContextMapper` based on the type of `LdapUserDetails` class requested, which is configured by `user-details-class` attribute of `ldap-authentication-provider`. If you are using your own context mapper then configure it using the attribute `user-context-mapper-ref`.

Comment: Mind shedding more light on how to configure the said user-details-class attribute of ldap-authentication-provider? Thanks!

Comment: Thing is I am using <security:authentication-provider/> to configure the Authentication Provider and that does not seem to have user-context-mapper-ref. How do you advice to proceed then? Thanks!

Comment: @dade If you have your own provider then you can configure similar to the OP's code except that instead of `<ldap-authentication-provider server-ref="contextSource"/>` you would use `<authentication-provider ref="ldapAuthProvider"/>`

Comment: Thanks @Ritesh. Found out why stuff was not working. The problem is project specific. Some overriding of the Spring configuration was going on that I was not aware of initially.